# Making drop-down navigation menus not affect other element positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

was wondering if there was a better way to handle what I'm trying to do. I've made a basic drop-down navigation menu where the menu bars are li and class elements with a set height with the overflow property set to hidden, which then animate in height to reveal the 'drop down' portion of the animation when hovered over with the mouse. I found however that other web page elements (like main content) would then be pushed around and re-positioned when the menu elements collided with them. I stop-gap fixed this by making the affected elements absolute positioning, but I can't help but feel there's a better, more effective way of fixing this.

Is there any way to make it so the navigation elements for lack of better word get 'ignored' positioning-wise?

Here it is in practice - the first 'article' area has been made to be absolute positioned - http://gamearticlesite.bbdesigns.ca/index.html

the code:

Jquery

```
 //When mouse rolls over  
    $("li.extend").mouseover(function(){  
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'250px'},{queue:false, duration:500})  
    });  

    //When mouse is removed  
    $("li.extend").mouseout(function(){  
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'35px'},{queue:false, duration:500})  
    });
```

CSS:

```
#headerNav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    color:#efefef;  
    margin:0;
    margin-left:75px;
    padding:0;  
}

#headerNav ul li{
    width:125px;  
    height:35px;  
    float:left;  
    color:#efefef;  
    text-align:center;      
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: absolute position is most common method. Go inspect a few menus in a browser console and look at the css used. Is very easy to do and will likely be good learning experience

Comment: Absolute positioning being used on the navigation menu or the other elements like I did? I've been trying to look at sites using the native chrome "inspect element" tools, but most of them are massive with multiple CSS and JS documents making it difficult to pick them apart.

Comment: menu elements....I misread what your fix was and is backwards. Look through this site...http://www.cssplay.co.uk/.... this guy has been playing with cutting edge menu CSS for years. Learn how to look at CSS in browser console...again it is very easy. Go inspect some menu plugins also

Comment: Absolute positioning is the best way to do it. It suits the common dropdowns needs perfectly. Don't apply the absolute positioning to header though. No need. Apply it to the dropdown itself: http://jsfiddle.net/uarnG/

Comment: _"but I can't help but feel there's a better, more effective way of fixing this"_ - Why? This is _exactly_ the effect absolute positioning is intended to have. (Except that as charlietfl said you've done it sort of backwards - you should make the _menu_ items absolutely positioned.)

Comment: @nnnnnn   actually I would wonder if there wasn't a better way too if I thought I had to absolute position everything but my menu on a page

Comment: OK, yeah, fair enough @charlietfl.

Comment: Ahaha, thank you guys! Feel quite silly having the right solution, just completely opposite. Quite happy with this now, I knew there was something 'off' with how I originally had it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer was that yes, Absolute Positioning is the way to solve this, but to use it on the navigation menu. In the example posted, on the ul element, not the individual li elements that would animate as that could cause issues with positioning of the li elements within the ul element.

Setting the position to position:absolute for the ul and giving a z-index property to make sure it's 'on top' of the elements it clashes with made everything work out just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
float:left
```

or

```
position:absolute
```